# Rails: Getting Previously Defined Traits in a Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factories

I have the following factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group_member do |f|
    f.user_id { rand(1..100) }
    f.group_id { rand(1..100) }
    f.membership { ["accepted", "invited", "declined", "requested", "denied", "left", "removed"].sample }
    if "#{membership}" == "accepted"
        f.host { [true, false].sample }
    else
        f.host false
    end

  end
end
```

The line:

```
if "#{membership}" == "accepted"
```

is throwing the error:

```
Trait not registered: membership
```

My intention is to find out if the previously defined trait "membership" is set to "accepted." I'm not sure how to access that trait, however. Any tips?

On another note, factory creation resembles form creation, in so far as there's a variable ('f' in this case) which is assigned various traits. Is there a word to describe these types of code blocks?

UPDATE: I've changed the factory to use an after_build call, but now I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `after_build=' for #<GroupMember:0x5dcb328>
```

The updated code looks like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group_member do |f|
    f.user_id { rand(1..100) }
    f.group_id { rand(1..100) }
    f.membership { ["accepted", "invited", "declined", "requested", "denied", "left", "removed"].sample }
    f.after_build do |obj|   
        if obj.membership == "accepted"
            obj.host = [true, false].sample
        else
            obj.host = false
        end 
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `"#{f.membership}"`? Or, indeed, just `if f.membership == "accepted"`?

Comment: Just ran it through and got the same error.

Comment: Also ran 'if f.membership == "accepted"', and throws a syntax error.

Comment: Fair enough, was mostly just a punt.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for giving it a shot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Re: Checking values already set.**

```
f.after_build do |obj|   
  # Test your obj.membership here. 
end
```

**Re: The error message complaining that `after_build` doesn't exist.**

Your definition syntax looks off. Change this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group_member do |f|
```

to this:

```
FactoryGirl.define :group_member do |f|
```

Comment: I'm now getting an error related after_build. Would you mind reading my update above?

Comment: What version of FactoryGirl are you using? The callbacks aren't bleeding edge, but they were not around at the beginning either.

Comment: I'm on master, 4.1.0. I'll check the docs to see if the callbacks have changed.

Comment: Looks like FactoryGirl's syntax has changed. It should now be "f.after(:build) do |obj|". This approach works with both my original syntax and the cleaner one you just recommended.